# Docker Compose Volume not mounted

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, volume

In my docker container, the volume is not synced.

`Dockerfile.dev`

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# php7.3
RUN apt-get clean && apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y unzip locales software-properties-common \
  && locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
RUN LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

# COPY Customized php.ini file
COPY ./deploy/services/php/7.3/php/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yq --no-install-recommends \
    apt-utils \
    curl \
    # Install php 7.2
    php7.3-cli \
    php7.3-bcmath \
    php7.3-json \
    php7.3-curl \
    php7.3-fpm \
    php7.3-gd \
    php7.3-ldap \
    php7.3-mbstring \
    php7.3-mysql \
    php7.3-soap \
    php7.3-sqlite3 \
    php7.3-xml \
    php7.3-zip \
    php7.3-intl \
    php-imagick \
    # Install tools
    openssl \
    vim \
    mysql-client \
    iputils-ping \
    sqlite3 \
    ca-certificates \
    && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

WORKDIR /var/www

# # Copy composer.lock and composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/

# Run PHP FPM service
RUN ["service", "php7.3-fpm", "start"]


# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.6'
services:
      my_app:
        build:
          context: ./
          dockerfile: ./deploy/services/php/7.3/Dockerfile.dev
        container_name: my_app
        volumes:
          - "./:/var/www"
          - "./deploy/services/php/7.3/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini"
```

The command I am running is

```
docker-compose build --no-cache
```

When I ssh in the container with `docker run -it {container_id}`, I cant see my other files from context root directory.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need to remove the volumes section from your compose, you overwrite all the files you copy or build during the build process in your dockerfile

Comment: Your Dockerfile is missing a `CMD` so it won't start PHP on startup.  `docker run` creates a new container from an image, but it never reads the `docker-compose.yml` file; you might be looking for `docker-compose up`.  But as @LinPy says, your settings there overwrite the code in the image with arbitrary host content so your results will be a little unpredictable.